# Update existing form based on current user Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that I want to update the values of based on the current user but I can not get my form to update when I click submit. Currently the Values are not updating

here is my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def student_update(request):
    #return UpdateView(request, form_class=UpdateStudentForm, object_id=request.user,    template_name='success.htm')
    form = UpdateStudentForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            m = form.save(commit=False)
            m.user = request.user
            m.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success.html')
    else:
        form = UpdateStudentForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "famu/profile.html", {'form': form})
```

my forms.py

```
class UpdateStudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('street_number', 'street_name', 'apt_number', 'city','state','zipcode')
    #def save(self, commit=True):
    #    user = super(UpdateStudentForm, self).save(commit=False)
    #    user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
    #    if commit:
    #    user.save()
    #    return user
```

my model.py includes the following code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Student(models.Model):
    CLASSIFICATION = (
        ('FR', 'Freshman'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
        ('GR', 'Graduate'),
    )
    TERMS = (
        ('F', 'Fall'),
        ('S', 'Spring'),
        ('Su', 'Summer'),
    )
    MAJOR = (
        ('CS', 'Computer Science'),
        ('CY', 'Computer Systems'),
        ('IT', 'Information Technology'),
    )
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    student_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=9)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASSIFICATION)
    enrolled_year  = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    enrolled_term = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TERMS)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=MAJOR)
    street_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    apt_number = models.CharField('apt #', max_length=10, blank=True, )
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField('Zip Code', max_length=5, )


    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)



class Grade (models.Model):
    GRADES = (
        ('A', 'A'),
        ('B', 'B'),
        ('C', 'C'),
        ('D', 'D'),
        ('F', 'F'),
        ('T', 'Transfer'),
    )
    TERMS = (
        ('F', 'Fall'),
        ('S', 'Spring'),
        ('Su', 'Summer'),
    )
    CREDITS = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
        (6, '6'),
        (7, '7'),
        (8, '8'),
        (9, '9'),

    )
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    course_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    course_number = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    grade= models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRADES)
    term_taken = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TERMS)
    year_taken = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)
    credits = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=CREDITS)
class Message (models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver')
    message_content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Gradapp (models.Model):
    student_id = models.OneToOneField(Student, primary_key=True)
    submitted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: why have you overridden your MF fields to a list of strings? You're losing all the object info contained in that list.

Comment: i'm not sure what line you are referring to?

Comment: fields = ('street_number', 'street_name', 'apt_number', 'city','state','zipcode'). Where are these fields declared, or tied to the Student model?

Comment: oh sorry I should show the full model method I have updated the question to include the full model implementation

Answer (score 0):

According to your models.py, this line in views.py:

```
m.user = request.user
```

should be

```
m.username = request.user
```

Comment: When I do this, the username becomes the id of the request.user object

Answer (score 0):

The request.POST contains the form data, but where you instantiate the form at the top, it may be an empty QueryDict as well, if it's a GET. This is most likely causing the issue, you should be passing None if it's a GET. Try this:

```
form = UpdateStudentForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
```

Note that this also cleans up your code, as you don't need to make another form for the GET:

```
form = UpdateStudentForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        m = form.save(commit=False)
        m.user = request.user
        m.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success.html')
return render(request, "famu/profile.html", {'form': form})
```